# Automating a Google forms with Python

Tags: python, google-forms, build-automation

I am automating a google form with Python to be used for a daily form with predetermined values for a covid 19 questionnaire for a school. My question is this, where in my code do I implement the code save the predetermined values given without having them reentered daily by the user?

Comment: Anywhere in your code, via the appropriate data-structure. Likely either a `list` or a `dict`. You may also modify anywhere where there is an `input` to simply have the appropriate `str` answer.

Comment: Thank you! I just wasn't sure where I had to place it